# Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'row'

Tags: python, excel, row, openpyxl, col

I have code:

```
def add_to_database(object_name, value):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(DATABASE_FILE)
    worksheet = workbook[DATABASE_SHEET]
    object_row = None
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row = 1, max_row = worksheet.max_row + 1, values_only = True):
        if row[0] == object_name:
            object_row = row
            break
    if object_row:
        worksheet.cell(row = object_row[0].row, column = 2).value += value
    else:
        last_row = worksheet.max_row
        worksheet.cell(row = last_row, column = 1).value = object_name
        worksheet.cell(row = last_row, column = 2).value = value
    workbook.save(DATABASE_FILE)
    workbook.close()
```

I get an error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'row'
on the line:
worksheet.cell(row = object_row[0].row, column = 2).value += value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like cargo-culted code with no reference to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get the row value from a string, something that doesn't have a row value. Also you'll want to create a loop that takes the row number into account to be able to do this.

```py
import openpyxl

DATABASE_FILE = "your_database_file.xlsx"
DATABASE_SHEET = "your_database_sheet"

def add_to_database(object_name, value):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(DATABASE_FILE)
    worksheet = workbook[DATABASE_SHEET]
    object_row_num = None
    for row_num, row in enumerate(worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=worksheet.max_row, values_only=True), start=1):
        if row[0] == object_name:
            object_row_num = row_num
            break
    if object_row_num:
        worksheet.cell(row=object_row_num, column=2).value += value
    else:
        last_row = worksheet.max_row + 1
        worksheet.cell(row=last_row, column=1).value = object_name
        worksheet.cell(row=last_row, column=2).value = value
    workbook.save(DATABASE_FILE)
    workbook.close()
```

Untested, but *should* work. Lmk if it doesn't.